# which authentication method is best for a client app having to interact with a web application that has authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, session, cookies, authlogic

Just wondering what people would suggest for an approach for a WinForms client that will have to interact with my web application (ruby on rails, which will use AuthLogic for authentication).

For example options such as:
*  authentication each HTTP request,
* gets a token for the session until it times out
* other?

This can be treated as a generic client to web application type question I think, i.e. web application using the standard HTTP/HTTPS etc.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got you boy..!!! I got you raynes..!!!

(..once passed the gone in sixty seconds quote)

voila:
[Here is what you need ...How to create an api in ruby on  rails](http://www.whatcodecraves.com/articles/2008/11/25/how_to_make_an_api_for_a_rails_app/)

Answer (score 0):

You could get WinForms to send an XML request containing the username and encrypted password and then have the server return a user object in the response as well as setting a session variable.

I don't know what you can get back from WinForms, just a guess.